# Pérdida de memoria en aplicación multihilo

Tags: c#, wpf, hilos, manejo-de-memoria, out-of-memory-error

El escenario es el siguiente: una aplicación con varios hilos: 2 para pedir datos a diferentes fuentes, 3 para actualizar diferentes informaciones en pantalla, y 1 para reproducir audios a demanda.

El problema: la aplicación tiene que funcionar non-stop, y al arrancar funciona bien, pero al cabo de un tiempo (no siempre el mismo, suelen ser entre 5 y 8 horas) acaba fallando. La traza de error apunta
a uno de los hilos de pintado, en donde me salta la excepción

> System.OutOfMemoryException

durante 5 o 6 minutos, hasta que al final el programa se para.

Ese thread ejecuta dentro otros dos, que son 
2 animaciones (fadeIn,fadeOut) que duran 1seg, antes y después de actualizar la información. Si quito esas animaciones el programa no falla (almenos durante 24h). Me gustaría mantener las animaciones, y que memoria
ayudarais a detectar qué estoy haciendo mal, supongo que no estoy liberando recursos o algo parecido.

Por mi parte he mirado dos cosas:

1) Memoria de la aplicación: he creado esta variable

```
PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
```

y en cada pasada del thread lo ejecuto mediante

```
"RAM disponible: " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB"
```

El valor está siempre en torno a 3.5/4Gb, así que no parece estar perdiendo memoria.

2) Número de threads: leí que hay un límite de threads que una aplicación puede crear, y pensé que si no los estaba cerrando adecuadamente quizá ese fuera el problema. Pero no parece tampoco. Ejecuto esto en cada pasada  y me da siempre un valor estable de entre 30 y 35:

```
"NumThreads: "+System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count"
```

Adjunto el código, y a ver si me podéis decir qué estoy haciendo mal:

Thread que pinta información (si quito las líneas de las animaciones la aplicación funciona ok)

```
while (true){
try{
    EscribirLogError("PintarTiempos - RAM disponible: " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB",false);
    tiempoPrevisiones = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIEMPOPREVS"]);

    //Animación quitar tiempos
    tFadeOut = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FadeOut));
    tFadeOut.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    tFadeOut.Start();
    //Pintar tiempos
    this.window.pintaTiempos(previsiones);
    Console.WriteLine("NumThreads: " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
    EscribirLogError("NumThreads: "+System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count,false);
    //Animación tiempos nuevos
    tFadeIn = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FadeIn));
    tFadeIn.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    tFadeIn.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(tiempoPrevisiones * 1000);

}catch(Exception e){
    EscribirLogError("PintaTiempos:" + e.Message, true);
}

public void FadeIn()
    {
        TimeSpan fadeInTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01");
        Double opacityFinalFadeIn = 1d;
        Thread.Sleep(750);
        this.window.FadeIn(fadeInTime, opacityFinalFadeIn);
    }`
```

La función fadeIn de la instancia this.window

```
public void FadeIn(TimeSpan fadeInTime, Double d)
{
  this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
  {
    try
    {
        var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, fadeInTime);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.lblTiempos.Length; i++)
        {
            this.lblLineas[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
            this.lblDestinos[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
            this.lblTiempos[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.programa.EscribirLogError("FadeIn.Dispatcher:" + e.Message, true);
    }
  }), null);
}
```

Comment: Solo como referencia, haz el [tour]. Bienvenido!

Comment: Creo que necesitariamos ver un poco mas de esas clases. El error se puede dar no necesariamente por esos graficos, si no por otras cosas que contengan esas clases. Mas alla de eso, si llamas a esas clases lo suficientemente rapido como para no darle tiempo al GC para actuar, se va a llenar la memoria. Recuerda que no se habla de memoria total, si no de memoria contigua. Puede que tu app ocupe siempre la misma meroria, pero si va dejando baches que despues no puede llenar va a llegar a ese problema. Es de 32 o 64?

Comment: Tour hecho!
La maquina es de 64 bits.
Lo de la memoria contigua no lo creo, si de 8 gigas me quedan 3-4 libres, por muy fragmentada que esté no creo que sea ese el problema no?
He puesto solo estos trozos de código por dos motivos: que, pese a haber varios threads, y que todos ellos escriben en el log si fallan, SIEMPRE falla este, y que si quito este trozo de código la aplicación va bien.
No obstante ningún problema, qué más quieres ver? Concretame un poco lo que buscas, pq el programa principal son 800 líneas y la clase que hereda de Window otras 500... Donde lo pongo? Edito la pregunta?

Comment: Todo lo que sea imagenes, y similares, se vuelve memoria no manejada que segun el tamaño y a menos que se garantice el dispose adecuado, agota la memoria que el programa utiliza para trabajar, sugeriria que garantizaras el dispose de tus animaciones.

Comment: Ayer arreglé el problema. En lugar de invocar las animaciones (FadeIn,FadeOut) como nuevos threads lo hice como funciones normales, dentro del thread al que pertenecen. El comportamiento en la UI es prácticamente el mismo, y no han saltado excepciones en todo un día. No obstante, no entiendo porqué colapsa si las invoco como threads, ya que entiendo que los recursos se liberan correctamente. Así que me gustaría seguir con el tema simplemente para aprender, puesto que no veo qué estoy haciendo mal al invocar los threads.

Comment: Cómo garantizo el dispose de las animaciones @Lcop? Ya había probado lo siguiente en cada iteración, para liberar las animaciones anteriores, pero no funcionó.
`this.lblLineas[i].BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, null);`

Comment: las funciones de animacion deben contener una implementacion de IDisposable que permita invocar la funcion dispose de los objetos que acumulan memoria

Answer (score 0):

Como practica general no deberías utilizar Thread.Sleep() en producción.

> Los hilos son recurso limitados, necesitan 200,000 ciclos para crearse y 100,000 ciclos para destruirse. Por defecto, reservan 1 megabyte de memoria virtual para su pila y usan de 2,000 a 8,000 ciclos por cada cambio de contexto. Esto hace que cualquier hilo en espera sea un gran desperdicio.

[Referencia Peter Ritchie](https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/)